# Get oozie workflowId based on workflow name with wild cards

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am looking for a command to get the list of all workflowIds for a given name using wildcards.

I am using the below command to get the details when I know the complete workflow name from workflow.xml

```
oozie jobs -oozie http://oozie.org:11000/oozie
-filter name="workflow name"
```

Here, how should I use the filter command when I know only the partial name of the workflow using wild card.

How to use the wild cards in the `name` value?
Looking for something like

```
oozie jobs -oozie http://oozie.org:11000/oozie
    -filter name="workflo*"
```

which will list out all the workflowId details for the workflows whose name starts with '*workflo*'

Answer (score 5):

Till oozie 4.3.0 release, it does not support wild card based filtering. In the Oozie 5.0 It is expected to be there.

If you are building the Oozie for your enterprise or project you have apply the [OOZIE-2225](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2225) and use.